# JAWS wordnet similarity

Tags: java, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

I use JAWS for normal wordnet to find similarity between words.

I installed wordnet 2.1 and I added the jar file : edu.mit.jwi_2.1.4.jar and edu.sussex.nlp.jws.beta.11.jar and I copier the WordNet-2.1-InfoContent in D: \ Program Files \ WordNet \ 2.1 but i have this problem when i run my application

```
Loading modules
set up:
... finding noun and verb <roots>
... calculating IC <roots> ...
... ICFinder
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program Files\WordNet\2.1\WordNet-InfoContent-2.1 (Access Denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
... DepthFinder
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
        at edu.sussex.nlp.jws.ICFinder.setup(ICFinder.java:135)
        at edu.sussex.nlp.jws.ICFinder.<init>(ICFinder.java:44)
        at edu.sussex.nlp.jws.JWS.<init>(JWS.java:76).
```

please help and thank you.

Comment: Which user are you running your program as? Check that this user has permissions to read the file ```D:\Program Files\WordNet\2.1\WordNet-InfoContent-2.1```.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if JAWS can be used to measure similarity between the words.

Answer (score 0):

Download **wordnet** from http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/

Put it's contents in this directory: `C:\Program Files\WordNet\2.1\`

Added the jar file: `edu.mit.jwi_2.1.4.jar` and `edu.sussex.nlp.jws.beta.11.jar`.

Downloaded this file?
http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/Data/WordNet-InfoContent-2.1.tar.gz

Extract it and copy into `C:\Program Files\WordNet\2.1`  (ie inside 2.1 folder)