# How to use JAWS for Wordnet similarity?

Tags: java, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

I've searched for java library for wordnet similarity and also found some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976537/wordnet-similarity-in-java-jaws-jwnl-or-java-wnsimilarity) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217499/jaws-wordnet-similarity). I have done all of instructions mentioned in those questions but still when I use below code `JWS` isn't recognized.

[image]

How can I solve it?Thanks